# php:search facebook pages by name through facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

my question is simple i want to send a keyword to the api to search pages that have the same keyword in name of the page and i want to return all pages with details like every page with it number of likes and about section etc...

what i do that i download facebook php sdk and i follow the docs and i use the following code.

i make an app on Facebook developer account  and i use the app id and secret (and the app is live);

```
    <?php
require_once('facebook/autoload.php'); // change path as needed

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => '*****',
'app_secret' => '******',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
//'default_access_token' => '{access-token}', // optional
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
// app directory could be anything but website URL must match the URL   
given in the developers.facebook.com/apps
define('APP_URL', 'http://kout-kw.com/auto_search/testf.php'); 
$permissions = []; // optional

try {
if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
    $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
} else {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
}
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
// When Graph returns an error
echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
}
if (isset($accessToken)) {
if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
} else {
    // getting short-lived access token
    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
    // OAuth 2.0 client handler
    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
    // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
    $longLivedAccessToken =    oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;
    // setting default access token to be used in script
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
   }
// redirect the user back to the same page if it has "code" GET variable
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    header('Location: ./');
}



// type can be user, group, page or event
$search = $fb->get('/search?q=programming&type=page');
$search = $search->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
foreach ($search as $key) {
    echo $key['name'] . '<br>';
}
// Now you can redirect to another page and use the access token from 
$_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
} else {
// replace your website URL same as added in the
//developers.facebook.com/apps e.g. if you used http instead of https and 
//you used non-www version or www version of your website then you must   
//add 
//   the same here
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(APP_URL, $permissions);
echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
}
```

when i run the code a page appear with text Log in with Facebook!
i click on it and i get the following error

Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

### what i should do please?

### update:

i solve this error it was that i should put the redirectit url in the facebook login settings however now i have new problem

Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match.

any ideas?

---

UPDATE
i solve the past error by adding

```
$_SESSION['FBRLH_state']=$_GET['state'];
```

the problem now is i get no error but the following code not give me any output?

any one know why?

```
    // type can be user, group, page or event
$search = $fb->get('/search?q=programming&type=group');
$search = $search->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
foreach ($search as $key) {
    echo $key['name'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Please don’t create duplicates of your own questions, especially so shortly after you asked the first time. https://stackoverflow.com/q/51748735/1427878

Comment: any ideas please?

Comment: the title of this question suggests a different problem that the question body...

Answer (score 0):

Go to your app settings in facebook developers page, then go to Settings>Basic,

Here you will find App Domains field, marked in yellow -

[image]

Here you need to mention the full qualified domain name of where your app resides.

Then things will work.

Comment: what is the value you put? it might be an issue with the way you entered the url.

Comment: i try (http://kout-kw.com) with http - not worked too, i get the same error

Comment: Please check your code where you might have mentioned a different url than what you've configured on your app